# Ir da Activity principal para Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragment

Estou construindo um app em Android e nele terei entre as diversas activities um fragment para perfil de usuário.

O problema é que precisaria, a partir da seleção do perfil, ir da activity principal para o fragment. 
Mas estou com problemas na transação.

Não sei se estou usando a intent de maneira errada ou algo do tipo, vou deixar o codigo da activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.nav_Cadastrar)
  {
       Intent cadastrar = new Intent(NossaVozActivity.this, CadastroActivity.class);
       startActivity(cadastrar);
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_Login)
    {
      Intent login = new Intent(NossaVozActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(login);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_Denuncia)
    {
        Intent denuncia = new Intent(NossaVozActivity.this, DenunciaActivity.class);
        startActivity(denuncia);
    }
    else if(id == R.id.nav_perfil)
   {
     Intent perfil = new Intent(NossaVozActivity.this,PerfilFragment.class);
      startActivity(perfil);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_Sair)
    {

        {
        Intent fim = new Intent(NossaVozActivity.this, FimActivity.class);


        startActivity(fim);}

    }



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo à comunidade! Qual é o problema que está ocorrendo? A aplicação quebra quando tentas ir para outra Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é, `startActivity()` server para iniciar uma atividade e não um fragmento,para manusear fragmentos você precisa de um `FragmentTransaction`, para iniciar seu fragmento você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
PerfilFragment perfilFrag = new PerfilFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, perfilFrag, perfilFrag.getTag()); //Você pode criar sua própria tag
ft.commit();
```

`R.id.fragmentContainer` é uma View do seu layout que você irá utilizar para mostrar seus fragmentos, `add()` adiciona o fragmento a esta View, se você desejar substituir o fragmento você irá utilizar `replace()`, mais informações sobre a criação e a utilização dos fragmentos você pode encontrar na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) do android.

Comment: Resolveuuuuuuuuuuuuu !!!!!!!! Obrigado Meu amigo !!

Comment: @luisrobertoBarbosa obrigado, poderia marcar a minha resposta?

Comment: Considere feito !